# Django Rest Framework Save Data from Serializer to Model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to Save Data from Serializer to Model Database. Following is an example Code but Not Saving Data to Database!

For Example I am using a Sample Example View:

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', ])
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        s = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        if s.is_valid():
            s.save()
            return Response(s.data, status=201)
        else:
            return Response(s.data, status=203)
    else:
        return Response("", status=404)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db.models import Model
from django.db import models


class UserDetails(Model):
    userid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)


class UserLogin(Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(UserDetails, on_delete=None)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import UserLogin, UserDetails


class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    userid = serializers.Field()
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return UserLogin.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: Did you get any error? Whats your current response?

Comment: I got that Solved but Can you justify how do i refer to the Foreign Key in The Model from the Serializer?

Comment: Can you share the solution here?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/
Refer Here!

Comment: Your model class should be like this `class UserDetails(models.Model)`. If you have found the solution please post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers

from api.models import UserLogin, UserDetails


class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    userid = serializers.Field()
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return super().create(validated_data)
```